# Where is `filetype plugin` defined and how to override it?

Tags: python, vim, indentation, vim-plugin

I am trying set python indentation to use 2 spaces instead of 4 (or 8) spaces. I put the following in my  `~/.vimrc`:

```
set expandtab
set shiftwidth=2
set softtabstop=2
set tabstop=2
```

This works well, as long as I **do not** put `filetype plugin on` in the config as well. When I **do** have `filetype plugin on`, when I open a python file, `set tabstop?` will return 8 and the indentation got messed up.

So my questions are: (1) how does the `filetype plugin on` work and where is the filetype-specific config files located? (2) how can I override the filetype-specific config in my `~/.vimrc` (or somewhere else)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. How does the `filetype plugin on` work and where is the filetype-specific config files located?

   `filetype on` enables filetype detection, which does exactly what the name implies.

   `filetype plugin on` enables both filetype detection and filetype plugins, which are vimscript files that contain filetype-specific commands for setting various options, defining mappings, etc. Those ftplugins are located under `$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/` and you can make your own under `~/.vim/ftplugin/` or `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/` as well as various places under `&runtimepath` and/or `&packpath`.

   Judging by the "python" tag, the ftplugin you are having problems with is `$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/python.vim`, which has this snippet:

   ```
   if !exists("g:python_recommended_style") || g:python_recommended_style != 0
       " As suggested by PEP8.
       setlocal expandtab tabstop=4 softtabstop=4 shiftwidth=4
   endif
   ```
2. How can I override the filetype-specific config in my `~/.vimrc` (or somewhere else)?

   **In general**, you can choose between two methods:

   - Add `FileType` autocommands in your `.vimrc`:

     ```
     augroup myFiletypes
         autocmd!
         autocmd FileType foo setlocal this=that
         […]
     augroup END
     ```
   - Put your settings in their own ftplugins:

     ```
     " in after/ftplugin/foo.vim
     setlocal this=that
     ```

   The latter is cleaner.

   **In this specific case**, the feature is behind a global variable so you simply keep your settings in your `.vimrc` "as-is" and add the following line (which will drive your coworkers mad):

   ```
   let g:python_recommended_style = 0
   ```

   as per `:help ft-python-plugin`.

Answer (score 1):

First enable loading the plugin files for specific file types with

```
filetype plugin on
```

> This actually loads the file "ftplugin.vim" in 'runtimepath'.
> The result is that when a file is edited its plugin file is loaded (if there is one for the detected filetype).

You can enable loading the indent file with:

```
filetype indent on
```

You can merge it on :

```
filetype plugin indent on
```

Then customize you rule for python:

```
au FileType python  set et sts=2 sw=2 ts=2
```